# Using CSS to force showing right single quotation mark instead of apostrophe

Tags: html, css, apostrophe, single-quotes

For some reasons I want that my static blog shows right single quotation mark (`’`) where there is an apostrophe (`'`). Is it possible to force it using CSS?

Comment: Try changing the font-family. It seems the font-family's apostrophe and right single quotation is similar.

Comment: Thank you @ChiragManiar, I always use Georgia, and it presents them with different characters.

Comment: You can get the system to pick up a character from a different font. Would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Important***:  CSS is not meant to change or replace text. You can use some client-side scripting language like Javascript or Server-side languages to do text change functionality

***OP Solution***

It looks like a font issue, try changing the font that you have or completely removing the font family to troubleshoot. [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) is a good place to start testing your text, if you know your font name and can find it in there.

***HAck***: If you really want to hack it using CSS, you can wrap your apostrophe (') in a `span` tag and use `:before` or `:after` CSS selector to change its content using the `content` property. Again it's not recommended to do it and if fonts is an issue, you may see the same behaviour again

---

**Working Example**

```css
span {
  display: none
}

div:after {
  content: '>';
}
```

```html
<div>Quote <span> ' </span></div>
```